# What is 露わになる affecting in the following sentence, '才能の持ち主' (持ち主 to be specific) or '才能'?

Tags: adverbs, nouns

> それも生死に関わる窮地に陥って、　初めて**露わになる才能の持ち主**です。」

I know that 才能の持ち主 (as the の is a possessive の) can mean 'owner of talent'.

Question is, what is 露わになる affecting in the above sentence, the 'talent' itself, or the 'owner of talent'?

Comment: Related: [Learn JLPT N3 Grammar: てはじめて (te hajimete)](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%A6%E3%81%AF%E3%81%98%E3%82%81%E3%81%A6-te-hajimete/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「初{はじ}めて露{あら}わ**になる**」is the 修飾語{しゅうしょくご} and from the context, I would say that「**才能{さいのう}**」is the 被{ひ}修飾語

Grammatically speaking, I believe the only real restriction is that the 修飾語 must come before the 被修飾語, not necessarily *directly* before it, but I think that is more common.

1. 「才能」 directly follows「露になる」
2. I think it makes more sense that ***"an ability"*** would be *"exposed* or *"revealed"* upon *"falling into a life-or-death situation"* than that a person (「持{も}ち主{ぬし}」) would

Comment: What if the person is the topic of the sentence via context, would that change what is being 'exposed'?

Comment: What is "exposed" is definitely context-sensitive. I think the grammar would work either way. Just from this snippet though, my impression is that it's the ability.